Why is there no audio on a newly installed Debian Trixie with XFCE, dual booting on Macbook Pro 2019 with Intel CPU and T2 chip?
There is no audio after dual booting Debian Trixie with XFCE, used ISO CD and Ethernet cable, on MacBook Pro (2019) with Intel CPU an T2 chip.
I followed the steps on this site.
(A) For PipeWire
$ sudo nala install wireplumber pipewire-media-session -
$ sudo nala install libspa-0.2-libcamera
$ sudo nala install libcamera-ipa
$ systemctl --user --now enable wireplumber.service
$ sudo nala install pipewire-pulse
$ LANG=C pactl info | grep '^Server Name'
Server Name: PulseAudio (on PipeWire 1.0.3)
$ sudo nala install pipewire-alsa
$ LANG=C aplay -L | grep -A 1 default
default
Default ALSA Output (currently PipeWire Media Server)
$ sudo nala install pipewire-audio-client-libraries
$ sudo nala install libspa-0.2-jack
$ cp /usr/share/doc/pipewire/examples/ld.so.conf.d/pipewire-jack-*.conf /etc/ld.so.conf.d/
$ sudo ldconfig

(B) For Bluetooth
$ sudo nala install libspa-0.2-bluetooth 
$ sudo nala remove pulseaudio-module-bluetooth

(C) Restart PipeWire Services
$ systemctl --user restart wireplumber pipewire pipewire-pulse

Audio is still not working? Why?
